# Filtering array of items depending on Input value in Angular

Tags: angular, filter

i want to filter list of items depending on the value entered in input form field.
Here is my code:

`post-list.component.html`

```js
   <input (keyup)="getPostByName($event)" class="form-control" type="text">
```

`post-list.component.ts`

```js
export class PostsListComponent {
  posts!: Post[]
  filteredArray!: Post[];
  constructor(private postService: PostsService) {
    this.posts = this.postService.getAll()
    this.filteredArray = this.posts;
  }
  getPostByName(event: any) {
    let filtered = this.posts.filter(post => {
      return post.title === event.target.value
    })
    this.filteredArray = filtered
    if (this.filteredArray.length <= 0) {
      this.filteredArray = this.posts;
    }
  }

}
```

the array is not filtered , i don't know what's wrong in my code

Answer (score 0):

It only works when you type the full title in the input field. You might want to change your implementation of the filter method to something like `return post.title.includes(value)` to filter by substrings.